# email send works via perl script but not shell script

Tags: perl, shell, email, unix, scripting

The email send works in perl but on in shell. Is my shell script right ?

If Perl script is works looks like the server SMTP conf is right.How can i find out what is causing the email not to work in shell script ?

`My perl script:`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMTP;

sub sendmail();

my $email       = 'abc@xyz.com';
my $smtp_server = '10.233.1.199';

sub sendmail() {
    my $s = Net::SMTP->new($smtp_server);
    $s->mail($email);
    $s->to($email);
    $s->data();
    $s->datasend("Subject: Test");
    $s->datasend("\n");
    $s->datasend("Testing\n");
    $s->dataend();
    $s->quit;
}
sendmail();
```

`Shell script:`

```
  #!/bin/sh

SUBJECT="some subject"
smtp=10.233.1.199
EMAIL=abc@xyz.com
echo "some message" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
```

Comment: Shell script looks to be error free. But assuming dummy data in your sample code, maybe there is a problem in your real values for your variables. I'd be surprised that your `smtp` variable has any effect. Export it maybe? Also, All Caps are more typical. OR comment it out altogether. See if the mail agent has sent back an error response? `mail` . Good luck.

Comment: yep exporting did the trick. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export the `smtp` variable, otherwise `mailx` will not see it. Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

SUBJECT="some subject"
export smtp=10.233.1.199
EMAIL=abc@xyz.com
echo "some message" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
```

Btw the `smtp` variable is not mentioned in `man mailx` in my system nor in another Linux system I have access to. But I found it mentioned in [an answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/137465/126831). That is to say, I'm not sure this would work on systems where it is not mentioned in `man mailx`, but if it works for you that's great.